Dell XPS 13 9350 no suitable firmware
I'm installing Ubuntu 22.04.1 onto a Dell XPS 9350.
The wifi wasn't working. After tracing for a bit, found a error log for the kernel module associated with the device.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/repos/linux-firmware$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[   11.316864] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   11.320246] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0xbadcafe, cnv-id 0x1080900 wfpm id 0x80005b20
[   11.320257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev a840/40e0, rev=0x460, rfid=0x20112200
[   11.498530] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-86.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.563961] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-85.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.564016] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-84.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.564060] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-83.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.564107] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-82.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.564157] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-81.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.564486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-80.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.564488] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[   11.564490] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-80
[   11.564491] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-86
[   11.564492] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

Related.
(I know this is the module used, via lspci -knn | grep Network -A3).
I checked out the git repo listed in the error log, but there is no firmware in that version range.
The closest one was iwlwifi-bz-b0-fm-c0-94.ucode, but it's not in the accepted range.
Thanks.

Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available. Dell usually is pretty good about updates. Either Windows, directly or https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/ shows two entries for your model. sudo fwupdmgr get-devices &
sudo fwupdmgr get-updates & sudo fwupdmgr update

Yes I did fwupdmgr update; it showed everything up to date.

Unfortunately I no longer have access to this laptop - but the gist was I couldn't find a solution.  Leaving open for others.

Of note, it looks like this model is end of life support.
